# How can i automatically convert Selenium HTML tests to Ruby Test::Unit tests?

Tags: html, ruby, unit-testing, selenium

I have a bunch Selenium HTML tests that are very convenient to edit using Selenium IDE. But my testing system uses Test::Unit tests. How can i convert my HTML tests to Ruby format? Converting them by hand is tedious and time consuming job, by the way sometimes i forget some test so this way is a no-go for a long run. 
So what can you guys suggest my?

Comment: same question to me, I need a commandline convert tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can open your HTML tests in Selenium IDE, following File > Export Test Case As... > Ruby (Test/Unit), then save the exported ruby file.

You have to focus on the Selenium IDE, or you won't see the correct menu if you're using Firefox on Mac.

UPDATE: there's an addon for batch convert: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/197691/

Comment: Well as i said in question. Converting every test every time bu hand is tedious job.

Comment: OK, I think what you need is: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/197691/

Comment: This is better but still i cannot make it into automated script.

Comment: Did anybody here find solution to this?